# .change() works in chrome console but not in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I have options, and every time I choose one option the websites shows me different thing.
For instance, if I choose "Italy", I get a link. If I choose "uk", I get an image etc. 
I'm trying to select one of this option with javascript or jquery. I'm trying to use

`$("#order_billing_country").val("IT").change();`

and it will select "italy" but it won't show me the link related to italy.

If I try it in the chrome console it works perfectly and I'll get the result for every country I select.

But doing it by a chrome extension it will select the option but the `change()` doesn't work and I don't get the link. Why in the console it works perfectly but not in my extension?
Can you help me?

Comment: Are you accessing it before the element exists?

Comment: i have tried to delaying 3000 ms and still nothing

Comment: So did you debug and see if you found the element?

Comment: i think it find it beacuase the value changes it select "italy" but it doesn't show the other informations that should appears after selecting the country

Comment: @epascarello If it didn't find the element, how would `.val("IT")` work?

Comment: Maybe the extension is running before you establish the `.change()` handler?

Comment: Content scripts run in *isolated world* so jQuery's internal gimmicks don't cross to the page world. Try using the standard DOM dispatchEvent to send a `change` event on the actual element (not the jQuery object), examples should be easy to find.

Comment: @wOxxOm and why the .val() works ? and ho i can use the dom dispatchevent to send a change ? i haven't find any events , thk you?

Comment: 1) Because `val` doesn't send an event, it simply reads the underlying DOM property. 2) Examples are really easy to find, don't give up.

Comment: @wOxxOm thk for you answer , i have tried with: document.getElementById('order_billing_country').onchange(); but it says onchange is not a function

Comment: That's not dispatchEvent, keep looking.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok now i'm watching dispatch event i have  tried document.getElementById('order_billing_country').dispatchEvent(event); but it says 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'.
 ... give me another hint please , (ps sorry if i'm bothering you)